# Best practice to manage SVN with a solution with multiple projects involved

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn, branch

*Before I start, the following is based on knowledge gained through usage of TortoiseSVN 1.6.x and ASP.NET web projects with Visual Studio 2008 as example.*

**Case Study**

Say, in a happy day scenario, a typical subversion repository structure can be somewhere similar to:

```
/trunk
    /Solution1
        /ProjectA
        /ProjectB
        /ProjectC
/tags
    /Solution1
        /version_1.0-rc
        /version_1.1
/branches
    /users
        /travis
            /Solution1
        /john
            /Solution1
```

- `Solution1` is a Visual Studio Solution containing 1 to many Visual Studio Projects.
- Users are working on their own solution branch, merging back to the trunk once in a while. No one is working directly on the trunk.
- Tags are created from trunk whenever there's a public release.

However in the real world, the project structure isn't that simple as many Visual Studio projects are shared between various of the Visual Studio solutions. The repository looks more like:

```
/trunk
    /CandyLand
        /Candy.Web.Pages
        /Candy.Web.Services
        /Candy.Tests
    /LollyApp
        /Lolly.App.WinForm
        /Lolly.App.Services
        /Lolly.Tests
    /Fundamental
        /Fundamental.BusinessObjects
        /Fundamental.DataAccess
    /Components.ExternalLibraries
        /Subsonic-2.2
        /Moq-3.1
        /Lucene.NET-2.0
```

Where in the example there are 2 products `Candy` and `Lolly`, and shared components (Visual Studio projects, DLLs) will be in `Fundamental` and `Components.ExternalLibraries` folders respectively.

Assume working off trunk, in order to work on `CandyLand` Visual Studio Solution, I need to checkout its files from repository as well as required components, so the solution structure may look something like:

```
+ CandyLand
    + Candy.Web.Pages
    + Candy.Web.Services
    + Candy.Tests
    + Fundamental.BusinessObjects
    + Fundamental.DataAccess
    + Subsonic-2.2
    + Moq-3.1
```

Moving the checkouts and nest folders together can be a bit annoying, we use batch scripts to do this for us.

**Problem**

I found it impossible to branch under this circumstance where user branches will only contain projects in branched solutions and not the shared projects.

Same with tagging, I cannot create a tag that contains both revision snapshot of product solution and its shared components.

.

**Am I going in the wrong direction? Have I made this repository too difficult to manage?**

Comment: Why not just move all folders under `/trunk` (CandyLand, LollyApp, ...) into a common root (`/trunk/Candy`)? Then you can branch/tag `/trunk/Candy` and produce a branch/tag that includes shared projects and libraries, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use svn:externals to include the folders under Candyland.

In the example below, the `*` marks an external:

```
+ CandyLand
    + Candy.Web.Pages
    + Candy.Web.Services
    + Candy.Tests
    * Fundamental.BusinessObjects
    * Fundamental.DataAccess
    * Subsonic-2.2
    * Moq-3.1
```

Comment: Sounds promising, I shall try this out. Is there a link to details page? Thanks.

Comment: Work like a charm. Thank you again. ps/ I setted up my Solutions by following http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html